# How to compile your own C-code as part of ModemManager

Tags: c++, gcc

I want to write simple C codes to use the functions in ModemManager 1.4.12 to use some of the functions provided in ModemManager to do modem related functions.
I have added the headers I need:

```
#include "config.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>
#include <libmm-glib.h>
#include "mmcli.h"
#include "mmcli-common.h"
```

Compile with gcc -o test test.h

but it complains that glib.h is not found.

When I compile with:
gcc -Wall `pkg-config --cflags libnm` `pkg-config --cflags --libs gio-2.0`
it complains that fatal error: libmm-glib.h: No such file or directory
When I use -I to include libmm-glib.h, it complains that ModemManager.h is not found.

Should I keep Adding directories with -I or is there a more proper way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: If your directories containing header files you need are all over the place, then you need to use `-I` multiple times to point to all the "all over the place" places you want to include from. There isn't any elegant general solution.

Comment: Right, but there is a problem, when I do that, the bare-bone program compiles. But I cannot still compile code that needs access to functions: undefined reference to `mm_modem_get_manufacturer' and I've added the header file that has the definition in. Ideas?

Comment: Undefined (it probably said unresolved, not undefined) reference has nothing at all to do with header files, it has to do with linking your code... it suggests you have not specified a library (but it can also mean you need to either change the ordering of libraries or use linker flags that allow for multiple passes through your libraries).

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you want to accomplish...

Do you want to build a separate program that uses *libmm-glib* to talk to ModemManager via DBus? If so:

```
 /* save as test.c and compile with:
  * $ gcc -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs mm-glib` test.c
  */
 #include <libmm-glib.h>

 int main (int argc, const char **argv)
 {
 ...
 }
```

Note that pkg-config requesting mm-glib cflags/libs should be enough, as that will pull any additional dependency cflags/libs, like glib/gobject/gio.

But from the looks of your code sample, you're also adding *mmcli* specific headers... so do you want to extend mmcli with new capabilities? If so, instead of giving custom gcc commands, you should extend the mmcli sources and if you need to add new files in the compilation of mmcli, just modify the Makefile.am under cli/.